# How to implement custom OpenID Relying Party in MVC 4

Tags: oauth, openid, asp.net-mvc-4, dotnetopenauth

I like the new MVC OpenID/OAuth login feature, but I want to know how to add a new login button, for example I want my users to login using their StackExchange account or using their OpenID url the same as in stackoverflow http://puu.sh/13rm0

How to do that?  Are there any samples showing this in steps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately the API Microsoft exposes is limited to login providers that are hard-coded to a specific URL -- not one that can accept input from the user before logging the user in, which OpenID requires.

You can add support for specific OpenID providers such as StackExchange by creating a class that implements `DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.IAuthenticationClient` and is hard-coded to use StackExchange.  A great example of this is the source code for [Microsoft's own provider for Yahoo!](https://github.com/AArnott/dotnetopenid/blob/master/src/DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet/Clients/OpenID/YahooOpenIdClient.cs).  Check it out, see how simple it is, then create your own that is simply hard-coded to `https://openid.stackexchange.com/` instead of `https://me.yahoo.com/` and you've got StackExchange login support.