# How to implement custom OpenId provider in Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, openid, intuit-partner-platform

I have to implement Intuit's openid authentication in our MVC 5 c# app. On [their site](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_quickbooks_online/0100_essentials/0085_develop_quickbooks_apps/0004_authentication_and_authorization/0011_from_the_intuit_app_center), the specify the custom URL to post your authentication requests to: 
`https://openid.intuit.com/OpenId/Provider`.

In the base template for an MVC app, I see the ability to enable well known openid providers:

```
//OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterMicrosoftClient(
//    clientId: "",
//    clientSecret: "");

//OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterTwitterClient(
//    consumerKey: "",
//    consumerSecret: "");

//OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterMicrosoftClient(
//    clientId: "",
//    clientSecret: "");

//OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterTwitterClient(
//    consumerKey: "",
//    consumerSecret: "");

//OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterFacebookClient(
//    appId: "",
//    appSecret: "");

//OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterGoogleClient();
```

But since I need to connect to some other provider, how do I do it? I assume I need to create a custom provider somehow, but have not been able to find any example of how to do that.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338224/how-to-implement-custom-openid-relying-party-in-mvc-4) looked promising, but it links out to the actual example and the link is dead.

Comment: Not sure if this will be helpful- https://intuitdeveloper.lc.intuit.com/questions/800930-reconnect-c-or-net-example and https://intuitdeveloper.lc.intuit.com/questions/1228669-how-to-configure-net-owin-to-use-intuit-openid-for-external-authentication

Comment: @SouvikGhosh thankyou for that, but from my understanding, that link deals with authorization to connect your app to quickbooks using OAuth, not single signon using Intiuit's openid provider...am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

You do have to create a customer provider. See the code for GenericOpenIdClient.cs in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12878441/how-to-use-openid-providers-with-unique-identifier-urls-in-asp-net-mvc4).